# How to use one pseudo selector into another pseudo selector in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to target the first element with `.a-todo` class, but at the same time not with the `.hidden` class. I wrote something like this, however it doesn't seem to be working. How can it be fixed ?

```
.a-todo:not(.hidden){
    &:first-of-type {
       border-top-right-radius: 4px;
       border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this approach can be used: Put border radius on all elements, and then remove it with the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

This example shows that it works, no matter where the `.hidden` elements are located.

```css
.a-todo {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  display: block;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.a-todo:not(:first-child) + .a-todo:not([class="hidden"]) {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a-todo hidden">Todo 1</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 2</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 3</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 1</li>
  <li class="a-todo hidden">Todo 2</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 3</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 1</li>
  <li class="a-todo hidden">Todo 2</li>
  <li class="a-todo hidden">Todo 3</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="a-todo hidden">Todo 1</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 2</li>
  <li class="a-todo hidden">Todo 3</li>
  <li class="a-todo">Todo 4</li>
</ul>
```